# Java, JavaFX. Использование картинок после преобразования проекта в .jar

Tags: java, javafx, изображения, jar

Java 11, JavaFX 11

**Как использовать картинку в проекте, который преобразован в .jar?**

Преобразовал проект в .jar, но при его запуске он не может найти картинки, они не отображаются в моем проекте.

Использовал для создания картинок конструкции вида `new Image("file:icons/area/doors/airlock.png")`, позднее используемых в `ImageView()`. При запуске проекта через IntelliJ IDEA картинки спокойно находились и отображались, но в .jar файле - нет.

Попытался погуглить, нашел информацию по `getResourceAsStream()` и `getResource()`, но в такой конструкции:

```
new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("icons/area/doors/airlock.png"))
```

вылетает ошибка: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null`

Конструкции вида `new Image(getClass().getResource("icons/area/doors/airlock.png").toExternalForm())` или `new Image(getClass().getResource("icons/area/doors/airlock.png").toURI().toURL().toString())` вызывают эту же ошибку.

Папка с картинками находится в корне проекта, но не в папке с кодом. Например `projectName/icons/area/doors/airlock.png`

Comment: Конструкция `getClass().getResource` говорит о том, что система будет искать файл в ресурсной папке (которой судя по всему у вас нет) по относительному пути отталкиваясь от местонахождения файла `getClass()`

Comment: @Maxim спасибо большое за подсказку! Погугил насчет ресурсной папки и нашел решение в похожем вопросе на stackoverflow. Теперь все работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для использования картинок нужно создать ресурсную папку. В IntelliJIDEA это можно сделать в контекстном меню после ПКМ по какой-либо папке, в которой будет ваша картинка/другой ресурс. Приведу пример из своего проекта:

[image: Пример пометки папки как ресурсной папки]

После этого картинку можно использовать, например, так:

```
new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icons/area/doors/airlock.png"));
```

Писать в пути к файлу ресурсную папку не нужно.